# Best way to switch to xserver-xorg-video-nouveau in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, nouveau, ubuntu-drivers

I want to *switch to the **Nouveau** drivers*. I'm using the Nvidia drivers in KDE, Ubuntu 20.04. What's the best way to switch to using xserver-xorg-video-nouveau? I have seen numerous threads talking about how to switch TO Nvidia drivers, but I want to switch to the open-source ones. Previously there was a GUI for doing this, but that hasn't been functional for a while and is actually no longer available.

The 'ubuntu-drivers' command doe not seem to work. I tried:

```
ubuntu-drivers install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

But it doesn't recognize the command and I have no idea how to switch to the 'xserver-xorg-video-nouveau' driver.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to remove proprietary Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
```

The `nouveau` driver is always installed unless you manually blacklisted it.

Comment: Does the ubuntu system automatically change to the nouveau driver when Nvidia's proprietary drivers are removed? I would hate to reboot and have no graphics. (It's happened before in the long past.)

Comment: Yes, it does. Unless you did something wrong before.

Comment: @Pilot6
When I do this and try to boot my system, I get green/red/purple-ish horizontal lines streak across the top of my display but no video. it seems like it's reached TTY mode as I can type things in and see very tiny pixels appear (in 4 different spots) as if it was displaying characters I'm typing, but no matter what I do I can't actually see what I'm typing nor can I get to a desktop environment. Luckily, I have Intel integrated graphics to fall back on and reinstall the Nvidia proprietary drivers, but I can't for the life of me get Nouveau drivers working. Any advice?